# CSS grid How to toggle children visibility without the need to change grid-template-columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

Given the following layout:

```
 <div id="grid" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: min-content auto; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <div id="first" style="width: 20px; background-color: green;">
      
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: cyan;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to toggle visibility of the "first" child so the second one will occupy the remaining space.

The grid seems to be doing a silly thing by re-assigning the hidden column definition to the next visible one, so after hiding the first child the second one becomes "the first" as far as the grid layout sees it and it inherently uses "auto". Since there's no content in the child child it just doesn't display anything. I'd expect grid-template-columns *to stick* regardless of the actual columns visibility.

If the child would got physically removed from the grid the latter would be in its full right to do that, but I'm only changing the  visibility.

Needing to manage grid-template-columns for such a scenario creates a totally unnecessary overhead in my opinion, I'd appreciate if people can share their thoughts on it.

I'm aware of the fact that some layouts for example those which use `repeat(...)` may not suffer form the issue, but I'm looking for a fix just for my scenario.

Comment: Please show how the first item is being 'removed/rendered invisible/not displayed...'

Comment: Sure, it's just child.style.display = "none".

Comment: 'but I'm only changing the visibility' - this is a misunderstanding of what display: none does.  See MDN - 'Turns off the display of an element so that it has no effect on layout (the document is rendered as though the element did not exist). All descendant elements also have their display turned off. To have an element take up the space that it would normally take, but without actually rendering anything, use the visibility property instead."

Comment: it does make sense. kind of. this it at very least inconsistent with let's say flex - if you have your second child with flex-grow:1 and then set display of the first one to none - it works. how come?

Answer (score 1):

You can give `grid-column: span 2;` to an element so that it takes up its own space + the space of the element that receives `display: none;`:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.one {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

.grid:hover .one {
  display: none;
}

.grid:hover .one + .two {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.two {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting, my layout is a bit more complex so it may not easily avail of col span, but that's an interesting approach. It just so counter intuitive to completely ignore child elements based on their visibility, they're still part of the DOM anyhow.